Why is skipping NULL columns on an INSERT slower?
I have a huge INSERT script that, for my sins, I am maintaining. It's huge and slow. That's not a show-stopper because performance isn't really an issue, we can leave it running overnight, but some improvement would be nice.
I thought that a large part of the bottleneck was my client sending the text of the INSERT statement over the network to the server, and that reducing the size to around a third would help, but in fact it hurts.
If I strip out all the NULL values and the column names for those NULLs, the script gets a lot smaller, but it's also slower to execute. I'm running a test with 10,000 INSERTs and it's like 6 minutes verses 3.5 minutes.
What's going on? Why would INSERT statements with all the columns specified but NULLS provided be faster than INSERT statements with fewer columns specified? I guess the database is having to do checks to see if a column has a default value (it doesn't), but I'm surprised it's that significant.
DDL
create sequence COMPANY_SEQ
INCREMENT BY 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 MINVALUE 1 CACHE 20;

CREATE TABLE COMPANY 
(   CO_ID                   NUMBER(*,0)        NOT NULL ENABLE
, COUNTRY_CODE            CHAR(2 CHAR)       NOT NULL ENABLE
, COMPANY_NUMBER          VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)  NOT NULL ENABLE
, CO_SHORT_NAME           VARCHAR2(70 CHAR)  NOT NULL ENABLE
, CO_FULL_NAME            VARCHAR2(512 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE
, START_DATE              TIMESTAMP (6)      NOT NULL ENABLE
, DUMMY_FLAG              CHAR(1 CHAR)
, DATE_DELETED            TIMESTAMP (6)
, EXPIRY_DATE             TIMESTAMP (6)
, PUB_FLAG                CHAR(1 CHAR)
, DATE_CREATED            TIMESTAMP (6)      NOT NULL ENABLE
, DATE_UPDATED            TIMESTAMP (6)
, MODIFIED                TIMESTAMP (6)
, DUPLICATE_CO_ID         NUMBER(*,0)
, BUSINESS_PARTNER_NUMBER VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
, PRINCIPAL_ACTIVITY      VARCHAR2(4 CHAR)
, ESTABLISHMENT           CHAR(1 BYTE)
, DATE_OF_ESTABLISHMENT   DATE
, PERSON_TYPE             CHAR(1 CHAR)
, CO_FULL_NAME_SEARCHABLE VARCHAR2(512 CHAR)
, SOURCE                  NUMBER(1,0)        DEFAULT NULL
, CO_TRADER_LOADED_ON     DATE
, RISK_FLAG               VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
, IS_HARD_DELETED         CHAR(1 BYTE)
, DELETES_SENT_ON         DATE
, AMENDMENTS_SENT_ON      DATE
, DATE_OF_EST             DATE
, PERSON_PROTECTED        DATE
, ZI_CCNN                 VARCHAR2(17)
, UA_STATUS               CHAR(1)
, ZI_EST                  CHAR(1)
, ZI_CONSENT              CHAR(1)
, ZI_SIC_CODE             VARCHAR2(4)
, ZI_CCNN_START_DATE      DATE
, ZI_CCNN_END_DATE        DATE
, ZI_CREATED_DATE         TIMESTAMP
, ZI_UPDATED_DATE         TIMESTAMP
, CONSTRAINT PK_COMPANY_ID PRIMARY KEY (CO_ID)
, CONSTRAINT CCNN_UK UNIQUE (COUNTRY_CODE, COMPANY_NUMBER)
);
CREATE INDEX ECNO_CO_LOADED_ON         ON COMPANY (CO_TRADER_LOADED_ON) ;
CREATE INDEX ECNO_EXPIRED_ON           ON COMPANY (EXPIRY_DATE)  ;
CREATE INDEX ECNO_FULL_NAME_SEARCHABLE ON COMPANY (CO_FULL_NAME_SEARCHABLE) ;

Full Insert
INSERT INTO COMPANY
(CO_ID,COUNTRY_CODE,COMPANY_NUMBER,CO_SHORT_NAME,CO_FULL_NAME,START_DATE,DUMMY_FLAG
,DATE_DELETED,EXPIRY_DATE,PUB_FLAG,DATE_CREATED,DATE_UPDATED,MODIFIED,DUPLICATE_CO_ID
,BUSINESS_PARTNER_NUMBER,PRINCIPAL_ACTIVITY,ESTABLISHMENT,DATE_OF_ESTABLISHMENT
,PERSON_TYPE,CO_FULL_NAME_SEARCHABLE,SOURCE,CO_TRADER_LOADED_ON,RISK_FLAG,IS_HARD_DELETED
,DELETES_SENT_ON,AMENDMENTS_SENT_ON,DATE_OF_EST,PERSON_PROTECTED,ZI_CCNN,UA_STATUS
,ZI_EST,ZI_CONSENT,ZI_SIC_CODE,ZI_CCNN_START_DATE,ZI_CCNN_END_DATE,ZI_CREATED_DATE
,ZI_UPDATED_DATE)
VALUES
(COMPANY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'UK','002060453000','UK002060453000','UK002060453000'
,TO_DATE('2024-04-22 11:32:46','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'',NULL,NULL,''
,TO_DATE('2024-04-22 11:32:46','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),NULL,NULL,NULL,'','','',NULL
,'','UK002060453000',NULL,NULL,'','',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'','','','','',NULL,NULL,NULL
,NULL);

Stripped Insert
INSERT INTO COMPANY
(CO_ID,COUNTRY_CODE,COMPANY_NUMBER,CO_SHORT_NAME,CO_FULL_NAME,START_DATE
,DATE_CREATED,CO_FULL_NAME_SEARCHABLE)
VALUES
(COMPANY_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'UK','002060453000','UK002060453000','UK002060453000'
,TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-04-22 11:32:46','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
,TO_TIMESTAMP('2024-04-22 11:32:46','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'UK002060453000');

Explain Plans
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name        | Rows  | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |             |     1 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | COMPANY     |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SEQUENCE               | COMPANY_SEQ |       |            |          |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Same plan is generated for each, unless I'm doing something wrong.
I have tried sorting the insert script by the column list so as to group similarly structured statements together. This reclaims nearly all of the performance that was lost, but it's still about 10% slower. This might be an acceptable for reducing the script file size by more than half, nearly to a third of the size (it's a big script!).

Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE statement for your table; examples of the two INSERT statements (with and without NULLs); and the EXPLAIN PLAN for those two INSERT statements.

What does ASH show your session is waiting on?  Pinpointing performance issues without any supporting data is a bit of a challenge.  My guess is that removing the NULL values means you have a lot of different sql_id values that need to be hard-parsed and will clog up your shared pool.  But that's a guess not knowing what exactly your INSERT statements look like.  If all your statements aren't part of a single PL/SQL block, I'd try that first so you're not waiting for the DB to ack each individual statement over the network

Okay I'll have to figure out how to do all those things. I'm not really an Oracle person. Also need to vet the table structure for anything that my client doesn't want making public. I can obf the column names.

By "a lot of sql_id values", do you mean that because each statement is structurally different then it needs to generate new query plans more frequently?

Here's a quick workaround that should speed things up considerably

alter session set cursor_sharing = force;
then your inserts
alter session set cursor_sharing = exact;

which should drop the parsing cost considerably.
If it turns out that the cost is network not parsing, then change your script to be chunks of anonymous blocks rather than single inserts, eg
begin
  insert ;
  insert ;
  insert ;
  insert ;
  insert ;
  insert ;
  ... (say 100 or so)
end;

which then lets you send larger batches of inserts in a smaller number of trips

With a / between each block?

I've done this, and it started out really well, about 10 times quicker. But then about half way through (900,000 inserts in begin/end blocks of 10,000 each) SQLDeveloper just stopped with a red exclamation mark on the Script Output tab. No indication of what went wrong, nothing in the ScriptRunner Task window either other than (Failed).

@PhilHibbs 900,000 inserts with your "stripped insert" sample implies you are running a 300MB file. That's a large file for a GUI to handle, and features like syntax highlighting might cause issues. Try running the file with the "@" command, or using a command line tool like SQL*Plus.

The file is just over 1GB, and yes I am using the @ command.

What happens when you use SQLPlus (its using a thick driver not JDBC)

I'll have a go at getting SQLPlus working and try that (getting a TNS error at the moment, not used it before on this machine)

If SQL Dev works, you can use the same string for SQL Plus, eg  sqlplus user/pass@//myhost:1234/myservice

"ORA-12650: No common encryption or data integrity algorithm"

are you using a cloud wallet?
